# how to create a rundeck user manually with read-only access to one, many, or all rundeck projects

Tags: rundeck

in /etc/rundeck/realm.properties, the inline documentation is obfuscating to put it mildly.

The default for admin is:

admin:,user,admin,architect,deploy,build

and now I want to create all the users with no write or create capabilities at all except for me and one other and for ALL projects.

What are appropriate fields for "John Doe"?

jdoe:,........ fill in ........

Thanks much - if there is a document which points that out clearly, that would be good too.

Cheers.

Comment: Their docs are atrocious.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your user in [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#propertyfileloginmodule) way:

   `username:password,group1,group2,group3,groupn`
2. Now, you need to add an [ACL](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authorization.html) (Access Control List) that manages the new user (or new group defined with the user). Go to Gear Icon -> Access Control -> + Create New ACL button.

For example, this ACL is focused on "group1" (execute jobs only):

```yaml
# Project scope
description: project level ACL.
context:
  project: 'MyProject'
for:
  resource:
    - equals:
        kind: event
      allow: [read] # allow read of all activity (jobs run by all users)
  job:
    - allow: [run, read] # allow read of all jobs
  adhoc:
    - deny: run # don't allow adhoc execution
  node:
    - allow: [read, run] # allow run on nodes with the tag 'mytag'
by:
  group: group1

---

# Application scope
description: application level ACL.
context:
  application: 'rundeck'
for:
  project:
    - match:
        name: 'MyProject'
      allow: [read]
by:
  group: group1
```

Keep in mind that you can use [LDAP/AD](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#ldap) to get users and groups, or [PAM](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#pam).

Also, you have a good [ACL](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authorization.html#example) example here.

Comment: Unfortunately it still allows deletion of jobs and other non-read-only activities. It was tested by admin creating a clone of a "whoami" job, logging out after having added the above acl, with the project named specifically from MyProject to the project name here, and then logging out, logging in as the user belonging to group1 in the /etc/rundeck/realm.properties (user named testuser) and testuser was then able to delete the whoami duplicate job. :-(

Comment: Are you sure? I tested that ACL again and any user of "group1" group cannot change anything. Keep in mind that the ACLs take effects around one minute after saved :-)

Comment: Also, check that another ACL does not override the rules of the first one. Regards!